# How can I track authenticated users in azure function using application insights?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I followed this guide (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2017/10/10/azure-function-integrating-monitoring-with-application-insights/) to enable application insights. I have also configured my function app to use the build in authentication for Facebook, azure ad, etc.. But in application insights I don't see any authenticated users being tracked out of the box. How is one supposed to do that when you have a functioning app implemented as a c# class library?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly how the built-in authentication you implemented works. 
If you want [the telemetry you send to App Insights in Azure Functions to have context](https://4pp1n51ght5.com/2018/02/15/monitoring-and-scaling-azure-functions/) - such as Authenticated User - I dont think you can get this out-of--the-box right now. You need to add it yourself.

If this UserId is sent as part of the request, you can add it like so:

Somehow get the authenticated user ID from the request

```
[FunctionName("MyFunc")]
public static async Task Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "MyFunc")] HttpRequestMessage req, 
TraceWriter log, 
ExecutionContext context)
{
    var userId = ? // Somehow get the user from the request
    var tracer = new ApplicationInsightsTracer(userId);
    ...
}
```

And the App Insights wrapper should look something like this

```
public class ApplicationInsightsTracer 
{
   private static readonly Lazy TelemetryClient = new 
                                     Lazy(InitTelemetryClient);

   public string UserId { get; set; }

   private static TelemetryClient InitTelemetryClient()
   {
            var telemetryClient = new 
                    TelemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration.Active)
            {
                InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
                                   ["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"]
            };
            return telemetryClient;
        }
   }

   public ApplicationInsightsTracer(string userId) 
   {
       this.UserId = userId();
   }   

   public void TrackEvent(string name)
   {
      var eventTelemetry = new EventTelemetry(name);

      // Add context to the telemetry
      telemetry.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId = UserId;

      TelemetryClient.Value.TrackEvent(eventTelemetry);
   }

}
```

Comment: That will do the job but only for the TrackEvent coming from the backend